# Not able to attach header with post request in volley in android

Tags: android, json, error-handling, http-headers, android-volley

I am hitting a web service using volley library. In this library I need to attach headers to post a request but I am getting error while hitting a web service i.e. "onErrorResponse : null"

// code for it

```
       JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("response", response.toString());
                    pDialog.hide();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.txt_error_occured, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("policyNo", policyNo);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            params.put("User-agent", "My useragent");
            return params;
        }

    };
```

// Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);

Comment: how do you know that error is because of headers?

Comment: Try this way: Instead of `JsonObjectRequest` use `StringRequest` and also don't add `Content-Type` in parameters only pass parameters which require for values. Sometimes response comes in string of json, newbie think that have to use JSON but it should require normal `StringRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use volley ? You can switch to Retrofit rather. As itis one of the best and fastest networking library.

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header

I had used this code 1.5 years before but has send j=raw json inside body and was perfectly working. please check this out once.

```
    public void updateUserData(final String jsonObject) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        showProgressDialog();
        String tag_string_req = "string_req";
        String url = Const.UPDATE_USER_HISTORY;


        final StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                if (offer) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TabsActivity.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                    getActivity().finish();
                } else {
                    fm.popBackStack("quiz2", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                    fm.popBackStack("quiz1", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                    fm.popBackStack("app", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                }
//                transaction.commit();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                header.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return header;
            }


            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return jsonObject.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer shows `StringRequest` while op is asking for `JSONObjectRequest`

Comment: Thats not the issue you can convert that to jsonobject later.         
JsonObject responseObject= new JsonObject(stringResponse);

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how you could add headers to a Volley Post request:**

```
final HashMap<String, Object> postParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
postParams.put("KEY_1", "VAL_1");
postParams.put("KEY_2", "VAL_2");

JsonObjectRequest mRequestEkyc = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        "your_url_comes_here", new JSONObject(postParams),
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                DisplayUtils.dismissDialog(mContext);
                //parseResponse(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        DisplayUtils.dismissDialog(mContext);
        DisplayUtils.displayToast(mContext, error.getMessage());
    }
}) {
    /**
     * Passing request headers
     * */
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("KEY_1", "VAL_1");
        return headers;
    }

};


final int timeoutMilliseconds = 300000;
mRequestEkyc.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(timeoutMilliseconds, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(mRequestEkyc);
```

*Hope this works for you*

Answer (score 0):

```
@Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String>? {
    val header: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
    header["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    return header
}
```

That's how to add header in POST request kotlin